# Call Modal when PHP form submits

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php form that works perfectly. However, when the form submits, I want to display a modal and take the user back to the homepage. I have looked this past two hours online but have found no conclusive evidence. My current code is;

```
if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
{       
?><script>
$(function() {
$("#thankyouModal").modal();
});
</script>
<?php 
}else{
    die('Could not send mail!');  
}
```

The form collects data then sends all data as an email. I have tried using only php, jquery, amongst everything else. I simply want a modal that says a brief thank you, your form has submitted whilst re-directing the user to the index.html page. Does anyone have any ideas?

Regards,
Michael

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Comment: In order to help you better we need to look at a larger part of your code. But just to get you started, one way you do this changing the submit button type to 'button' instead of 'submit' and then on the onclick event you would show the modal and then submit the form. But as you seem to be mixing php, html and js code, a code example would probably confuse you more than help. That's why I asked for you to post more of your code, so we can adapt it in a way you can understand.

Comment: Nelson, apologies. I have a php script within my html code. I have a form in my html code, which has a submit button. I literally just want a php if statement to say that if the form is successful, display a modal saying that it was a success and redirect the user to the homepage.

Comment: But how would you know the form is successfull ? in the php code or in the submit event of your form (i.e. n javascript) ?

Comment: Do you want the modal to show on the homepage? If so, the controller that renders your homepage will need to pass a variable to the home view like `$sent= true`. Or you could look into asynchronous posting with ajax, then show the modal when it completes.

Comment: Do you have a modal with `id='thankyouModal'`...?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the message while the form is posting (whether or not it will succeed), use jquery to swallow the onSubmit() event.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#thankyouModal").modal();
    $('form').submit();
});
```

If you care about if the email is successful, pass a variable back to the view and conditionally show the modal, but this will be serverside validation (will only know after form submission and re-rendering of the view). Otherwise look into doing an asynchronous post with `$.ajax`